# Custom scrollbar in textarea - jQuery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, scrollbar

I want to add a custom scrollbar to my textarea field, the problem is that every jquery plugins or scripts I found, only worked in divs.

I've searched for weeks, I can not find a single thing that will work on Internet Explorer and Firefox, because the other browsers are webkit so I can easy customize their scrollbars.

Help?

Comment: What if you made a div behave like a textarea? http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/AbKTQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use NiceScroll 3 plugin: [LINK TO WEBSITE](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/index.html)

It supports DIVs, IFrames, textarea, and document page (body) scrollbars.

It also supports IE.

Comment: Oh fixed it, thanks this solved my live I love you. Do you have anything like this that solves the Internet Explorer non-resizing-textareas issue?