# Custom scrollbar for textarea which compatible with IE8 and above

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I had found so many plugins and webkit for custom scrollbar but i did't got any perfect solution for textarea scrollbar, can anybody know to customize textarea scollbar and which is compatible with IE8 and above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use NiceScroll 3 plugin: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623837/custom-scrollbar-in-textarea-jquery-javascript?rq=1)

It supports DIVs, IFrames, textarea, and document page (body) scrollbars.

It also supports IE.

Got the answer from here

[Custom scrollbar in textarea - jQuery / javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623837/custom-scrollbar-in-textarea-jquery-javascript?rq=1)